# How many distinct functions can be defined from set A to P(B)?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

A is a set with n elements. B is a set with m elements. How many functions are there from A to P(B)?

I am not sure if my thinking is correct. If B is a set with m elements so P(B) = 2^m . Each element from A has 2^m choices to be mapped to. So is the total number of functions from A to P(B) = (2^m)^n ?

Comment: I meant functions, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is correct.  In general the number of functions from $C$ to $D$ is $|D|^{|C|}$ for exactly the reason you state.

Comment: What if there is an element in A that does not map to P(B)? Because we can't assume that all elements in A are mapped can we?

Comment: To be a function, every point from the domain must be mapped somewhere.  Otherwise, we speak of a partial function.  In that case you have $|D|+1$ in the base.